# The view accounts.views.register_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, django-templates, valueerror

accounts.views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    get_user_model,
    login,
    logout,
    )
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import UserLoginForm

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/account')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'reg_form.html', args)
```

myblog.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from accounts.views import login_view, register_view, logout_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('login/$', login_view, name='login'),
    url('fixed/$', register_view, name='fixed'),
    url('account/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
```

accounts.urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url('register/$', views.register_view, name='register'),
]
```

reg_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dle3L.png)

[Error I've got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO6LG.png)

I've passed with no error writing this type of code. That time, I didn't get any error. But now, I'm getting error. Help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view doesn't return any value if form is not valid, to fix this you can rewrite view like this:

```
def register_view(request):
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/account')
    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'reg_form.html', args)
```

`UserCreationForm(request.POST or None)` will authomatically initialize form with data if request method is `POST`.

Comment: Your solution is working. Thanks a lot @neverwalkaloner . But, what's problem with my code? Can you explain, please.

Comment: @MahmoodAlRayhan your code didn't have `else` part for `if form.is_valid():` so if form is not valid view doesn't return anything. New version of view return HTTPResponse in any cases event if form is not valid.

Comment: `UserCreationForm(request.POST)` is enough

Comment: @heykarimoff yes, but `UserCreationForm(request.POST)` will render form's `This field is required` erorrs for GET request.